# вывести несколько строк текста из input

Tags: input

Есть код:

```html
<form name="idform">
  <input type="text" name="id1" value="">
  <input type="text" name="id2" value="">
  <input type="button" value="Применить!" onclick="document.getElementById('x').innerHTML=document.forms['idform'].elements['id1'].value">
</form>

<h5>
  <p id="x"></p>
</h5>
<h5>
  <p id="y"></p>
</h5>
```

По кнопке выводит только x, как вывести y (не создавая вторую кнопку)?

Comment: Абсолютно аналогично, получить второе значение и, например, сложить. Вы учебники по javascript читали?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте такой код:

```js
document.querySelector('form[name=idform] input[type=button]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = document.forms['idform'].elements['id1'].value;
  document.getElementById('y').innerHTML = document.forms['idform'].elements['id2'].value;
});
```

```html
<form name="idform">
  <input type="text" name="id1" value="">
  <input type="text" name="id2" value="">
  <input type="button" value="Применить!">
</form>
<h5 id="x"></h5>
<h5 id="y"></h5>
```